# Jquery anchor tag display problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am unable to show an anchor tag to display itself using `.show()` in Jquery or javascript. Conn Window is visible by default. It hides and displays the div but it is unable to do the same with anchor. I have manually tried to change it in firebug/IE dev tools and it works there. It just doesn't work when I do it with jquery/javascript.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:connShow();" id="connTab" style="display:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
<div id="connWindow">Conn Window
    <div id="closeButton" onclick="javascript:connHide();"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery code:

```
function connHide()
{
    $('#connTab').show();
    $('#connWindow').hide();
}

function connShow()
{
    $('#connWindow').show();
    $('#connTab').hide();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "javascript:" URIs are bad - http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#javascriptURI. They're also only relevant in `href` properties, not in `onclick`.

Comment: you are missing the point of jQuery revolution lol :) you shouldn't use `onclick` attr or `href="javascript:..."` as this can be done with jQuery and better managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline CSS `display:none` is [overriding](http://simonjobling.com/blog/2008/jquery-bug-fix-hide-show-on-hidden-elements/) the mechanism jQuery uses to show and hide.

Hide the anchor programmatically instead:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="connTab" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
<div id="connWindow">
    Conn Window
    <div id="closeButton"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function() { // on document load
    $('#connTab').css('display', 'none');

    // I'm going to replace your inline JS with event handlers here:
    $('#connTab').click(function() { connShow(); return false; });
    $('#closeButton').click(function() { connHide(); });
});

function connHide() {
    $('#connTab').css('display', '');
    $('#connWindow').css('display', 'none');
}

function connShow() {
    $('#connWindow').css('display', '');
    $('#connTab').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: you are allowed to change style attr using the `.css()` or event `.attr('style','[values]')` so I am not sure what you on about overriding ? as he needs it to be hidden by default :)

Comment: ... The link you mentioned in your answer is not relevant to newer versions of JQuery, hence "out of date".  This bug has been corrected.

Comment: @Val: I mean "overriding" in the same way that an inline style on an element takes precedence over a style inherited from ancestors.

Comment: @John: Hmm possibly. I recall just recently having vague issues with `.show` and `.hide` when an initial style need be applied; I think I went for class [de-]application in the end. Will monitor.

Comment: tomalak is right, at least for the version (1.4.2) I'm using.

Answer (score 4):

Why not bind your click events in jQuery as well

```
function connHide()
{
    $('#connTab').show();
    $('#connWindow').hide();
}

function connShow()
{
    $('#connWindow').show();
    $('#connTab').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contab").click(function () { 
       connShow(); 
       return false;
    });
    $("#connWindow").click(function() { 
       connHide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good idea, but how does this examine the cause of the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to state `javascript:` for `onclick` events. Try changing to:

```
<div id="closeButton" onclick="connHide();"></div>
```

I would also change the first line to the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="connShow(); return false;" id="connTab" style="display:none; text-decoration:none;"></a>
```